# mock_redis or fakeredis for stubbing redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, rspec-rails

I am working on application that has resque and redis. I am using resque_spec to stub resque in request specs and my college though that resque_spec will stub redis but it doesn't. I tried mock_redis and fakeredis gems. I have a problem with mock_redis - it thinks that 'get' is undefined method. I don't have problem with fakeredis. But I want to ask which gem is better - mock_redis or fakeredis and why?

Comment: You don't have problems with fakeredis. You do have problems with mock_redis. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but my boss said to my college to add mock_redis and when I go to my boss and say to him that I replaced it with fakeredis I want to have good arguments :)

Comment: which is better?

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is a great site for getting some data about gem popularity and possible alternatives.

As of 2022-03-11 (more than 8y after question was asked), [mock_redis](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/mock_redis) seems the vastly more popular choice (500k monthly DLs) versus [fakeredis](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/fakeredis)'s 200k.

Personally, I've worked only with `fakeredis` and had no problems.
Running tests with either gem is a must.